# What's the meaning of "enterprising" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I checked a lot of dictionaries and I couldn't  find a suitable definition.
Here's the sentence:
Enterprising humans, animals, heroes, or gods will make a habit of acquiring the first fire from some divine source.

Source: [Miscellaneous Myths: Rainbow Crow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuwgZSjuznY) at 0:28 seconds.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I think I got it myself! I thought it was a verb but it's an adjective

Comment: What is the source? Did you write this?

Comment: @AIQ no, it's from a video called "rainbow crow" on the "overly sarcastic production " channel

Comment: If you found the answer in a dictionary then the question is off-topic.

Comment: idiomatic use: to be enterprising.